# Roslyn - replace node and fix the whitespaces

Tags: code-formatting, roslyn

In my program I use Roslyn and I need to replace a node with a new node. For example, if I have code like

```
public void Foo()
{
   for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      Console.WriteLine("");
}
```

and I want to insert brackes for for statement, I get

```
public void Foo()
{
   for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
      Console.WriteLine("");
}
}
```

I tried to use NormalizeWhitespace, but if I use it on for statement, I get

```
public void Foo()
{
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
   Console.WriteLine("");
}
}
```

However, I'd like to have for statement formatted correctly. Any hints how to do it?

EDIT:
I solved it by using:

```
var blockSyntax = SyntaxFactory.Block(
            SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.OpenBraceToken).WithLeadingTrivia(forStatementSyntax.GetLeadingTrivia()).WithTrailingTrivia(forStatementSyntax.GetTrailingTrivia()),
            syntaxNodes,
            SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.CloseBraceToken).WithLeadingTrivia(forStatementSyntax.GetLeadingTrivia()).WithTrailingTrivia(forStatementSyntax.GetTrailingTrivia())
);
```

However, the answer from Sam is also correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `.WithAdditionalAnnotations(Formatter.Annotation)`, but only on the specific element you want to format. Here's an example from the [NullParameterCheckRefactoring](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/NullParameterCheckRefactoring) project.

```
IfStatementSyntax nullCheckIfStatement = SyntaxFactory.IfStatement(
    SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.IfKeyword),
    SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.OpenParenToken),
    binaryExpression, 
    SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.CloseParenToken), 
    syntaxBlock, null).WithAdditionalAnnotations(Formatter.Annotation, Simplifier.Annotation);
```